# Attempting to Use String.Join on a Collection does not list Items only Name of Collection

Tags: c#, .net, string, list

Everywhere I look seems to have the same response but I can't find one to address the issue I am having.  I am trying to concatenate the items in a list of objects into a string.  However, what I get is the name of the page and the name of the object, the actual list values.

I tried:

```
string combinedLog = string.Join(",", logList)
```

I also tried:

```
string combinedLog = string.Join(",", logList.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray<string>());
```

What I get is PageName + Log, PageName + Log

This is the object:

```
    private class Log
    {
        public DateTime LogTime { get; set; }
        public string Result { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public Guid? ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }
```

and the list is:

```
List<Log> logList = new List<Log>();
```

I am trying to get a string like:
"10/21/2019, Fail, Acme, Could not Import, 10/21/2019, Success, ABC, no errors"

Comment: Are you wanting a single property from the `Log` class or a combination of all properties? `ToString` does not do the latter by default, so you need to define how you want to represent a `Log` instance as a string.

Comment: @DStanley  In other words I want(10/21/2019, Fail, Acme, Could not Import) for each object in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override [`ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8) method in `Log` class for that

```cs
private class Log
{
    public DateTime LogTime { get; set; }
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public Guid? ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
         return $"{LogTime}, {Result}, {ItemName}, {ErrorMessage}";
    }
}
```

And than concatenate `logList` into one string using `string.Join`

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like
String.Join(";", logList.Select(x => $"{x.LogTime},{x.Result},{x.ItemName}")) ..

Or use generics to get it

```
var fields = typeof(Log).GetFields();
var result = String.Join(";", logList.Select(x => 
                 String.Join(",", fields.Select(f => f.GetValue(x)))
             ));
```